# HTML5 Canvas, the operation is insecure, but it's my own image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, cross-site

I have an image stored in a different directory than my javascript, like so:   "../part1/part2/part3/image.png"

If I try to render it to a canvas, then call getImageData on it, I get "The Operation is Insecure".

A cursory google search shows that this often happens for cross origin images. Which is all well and good, but it's my image, on my own server.

**Is having a ".." in the path really enough to set the Cross Origin flag, or should I look for alternate causes for the message?**

My objective is to have images stored in a parent directory that any of several different subdirectories (with their own html and javascript) can access. Is this a bad practice, and if so, are there alternatives?

Edit: Slightly more digging shows that local files are considered cross origin by default, which is indeed how I am testing.  It's all well and good if this will work in production, but I want to test BEFORE putting it on my server. Any tips?

Edit: Yeah, I wasn't running a server. Guess there really isn't a better way then, huh?

Comment: Is your page loaded from the file system instead of being served via http?

Comment: Do you have Python or Node.js installed on your local machine?

Comment: For the "any tips", simply set up an localserver.

Comment: Your page needs to be delivered via http(s), otherwise, the same origin policy may not work as expected.